# How to test if a number is $n$th power residue mod $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $a\in\Bbb Z_p$ where $p$ is prime is there polynomial time algorithm (which means the algorithm should run in $O((\log p)^c)$ time) to test if there is a $b\in\Bbb Z_p$ such that $b^n=a\bmod p$?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the $p$-adic integers or just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: no not $p$-adic

Comment: Then every $a$ has at most $p-1$ different powers, namely $a,a^2,\dots,a^{p-1}$ since $a^{p-1}=1$ and $a^{kp+d}=a^d$. There are exactly $p$ different $a$ objects, so you can check every $a^n$ for $a=0,\dots,p-1$ and $n=1,\dots,p-1$, for a total of $(p-1)^2$ cases. Just check them all?

Comment: @AngeloRendina do you know what a poly time algorithm means?